# Union of two tables selecting * but only where there are no duplicates in certain columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, union

If I have two select statements:

```
select * from x as a
union 
select * from y as b
```

but I want to union a to b where b doesn't have the same records as a but only in columns a and b and not * columns, would there be a way to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select *
from x
union all
select *
from y
where not exists (select 1 from x where x.a = y.a and x.b = y.b);
```